# .to_stata(). Big data file causing python to crash

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I have in Pandas a dataframe with about 7 million rows and 1600 columns. I've successfully exported the file to Feather, but I would need to get into Stata.

I've been using to_stata() a lot in my code, and it's somewhat sensitive, but this is the first time I can't get the export done no matter what I do.

The dataframe has plenty of nan's, but they are necessary because different time series start at different time points and I need the distinction between 0 and nan.

Is there another way to get the dataframe to Stata or does anyone have a good piece of code to prep big dataframes to optimize the export?

I've tried to export it in chunks, but Python silently crashes after some time. One bottleneck might be that I'm exporting everything as strings to avoid other errors from the .to_stata() method.

Comment: Can you export in chunks? Can you determine minimal row length that triggers the crash?

Comment: Have you given a thought to split the dataframe itself into chunks and then export the chunks?

Comment: What is giving you trouble that requires exporting everything as a string? Fixing that could be the remedy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering the same issue, I ended up doing a workaround.

The data set had many holes, meaning empty cells that had to be distinguishable from zero-values. Moreover, the data included all types of dtypes, so that's why, at first, I used to convert everything to strings.

I had four dataframes in Pandas and before I merged them into the final dataframe I converted object columns to strings

```py
# Create a list of columns with object data types
object_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns

# Convert these columns to string (str) data type
df[object_columns] = df[object_columns].astype(str)
```

After this, I merged all the four dataframes on datetime columns and I exported the resulting dataframe in chunks to Stata. The progress was a mandatory thing because the export failed countless times silently.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define the output directory
output_directory = "/Users/xxx/"

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

# Define the chunk size (number of rows in each chunk)
chunk_size = 10000 

# Calculate the total number of chunks
total_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1

# Use tqdm to create a progress bar
with tqdm(total=total_chunks, desc="Exporting Chunks") as pbar:
    for i, chunk in enumerate(np.array_split(df, total_chunks)):
        # Export the chunk to Stata format
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f'output_chunk_{i}.dta')
        chunk.to_stata(output_file_path, write_index=False)
        pbar.update(1)  # Update the progress bar
```

I ended up having a directory with 700 .dta chunk-files. Then, I used a for loop in Stata do-files to merge them.

```
cd "/Users/xxx"

clear  // Clear the current dataset

// Define the range of file numbers
local start = 0
local end = 699  // Adjust this to the highest file number

// Iterate through the files and append them
forval i = `start'/`end' {
    local file_name = "output_chunk_`i'.dta"
    append using "`file_name'"
```

All in all, I'm still not exactly sure what caused the issue. The final Stata file ended up being 85 GB, so that was for sure one thing. I fortunately have the Stata MP version, so the file works for me.